# Error when updating video on brightcove in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, video, brightcove

I am trying to update my video on bright cove, but when I send a request it returns an error in return. This is my JSON request which I send

```json
{"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"myID","economics":"AD_SUPPORTED"},"token":"myToken.."}}
```

and response is:

```json
{"name":"MissingJSONError","message":"Could not find JSON-RPC.","code":211}, "result": null, "id": null}
```

Comment: Did you search the web for the error code that was returned? Help us all by trying to help yourself first. I just searched the web and the very first page that came up told me what the issue was.

Comment: this the issues for my code We got a null string for either the json parameter (for a non-multipart post) or the first part of a multipart post.

Comment: but again where is null string in my request?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the [Brightcove API Error details](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/media-api-error-message-reference).  For this error, the reason is listed as:

> 211   MissingJSONError    Could not find JSON-RPC.    We got a null string for either the json parameter (for a non-multipart post) or the first part of a multipart post.

It looks like the result is telling you that the ID is null.  If you are passing an ID, check that it exists and is the ID type Brightcove is expecting (ie, the brightcove ID vs. the reference_id).

You can check all the API params here: [Brightcove Video Cloud / Media API Reference](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/media/#Video_Write)